# How to Download File from AWS S3 with Laravel Storage and delete it after

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-s3

I am reworking Laravel Storage driver to work with Amazon S3 instead of local. All good so far.
The problem is that I can't use storage_path anymore (I think so)

I find out problem with code where I want:

1. Create file (pdf e.g.) (All good here)
2. Show response that file has been created successfully. (All good here)
3. Redirect to another URL, where I check if File exists. (All good here)
4. If File exists Download  (All good here)
5. Delete after Download (Don't know how)

Working code before S3:

```php
return response()->download(storage_path('app/folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename), $filename)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

Attempt (Working without delete):

```php
return Storage::download('folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename, $filename);
```

Attempts (Not working if want to delete):

```php
return Storage::download('folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename, $filename)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);

return Storage::download('folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename, $filename)->delete('app/folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename, $filename);

return response()->download(Storage::get('folder/'.$path.'/'.$filename), $filename)->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
```

*Storage driver is "s3" with root 'app' thats why is missing in Storage::driver('s3) ....*

Have no idea is there anyway to rework the code to working in this sequence. Or Have to totally rework the idea of the create->download->deleteAfter?

Comment: Have you found a solution?